# Second level cache: Spring 3.2.2 + Hibernate 4.2.0 Infinispan

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, infinispan

Trying to set up 2nd level cache with Spring and Hibernate.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" p:database="${jdbc.databaseType}" p:generateDdl="true"
              p:showSql="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">com.antaresgames.ad.lobby.repository.FixedDefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.tm.HibernateTransactionManagerLookup</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</prop>

            <!--https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Using+Infinispan+as+JPA-Hibernate+Second+Level+Cache+Provider-->
            <!--CACHE CONFIGURATION-->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.JndiInfinispanRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager">java:Cachemanager</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics">true</prop>
            <!--https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Eviction-->
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.eviction.strategy">LIRS</prop>-->
            <!--https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Eviction+Examples-->
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.eviction.wake_up_interval">2000</prop>-->
            <!--https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Eviction-->
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.eviction.max_entries">5000</prop>-->
            <!--max time entity is living in memory in idle-->
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.expiration.max_idle">60000</prop>-->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But due to the lack of [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Using+Infinispan+as+JPA-Hibernate+Second+Level+Cache+Provider) for Hibernate 4, I think that I cannot set up cache properly.

When starting application I see warning like:

```
jta.JtaTransaction - HHH000426: You should set hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class if cache is enabled
```

And when getting entity for repository it is making query everytime.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try removing `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class` and `hibernate.transaction.factory_class`. Those are old properties. If using Hibernate 4+, you just need `hibernate.transaction.jta.platform`. Also, you have defined `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` twice. Remove the one with `org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory` and remove `hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager` property

Answer (score 0):

You should only need the following cache/tm related properties:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cfg">infinispan.xml</prop>
```

Note that you may need replace InfinispanRegionFactory with JndiInfinispanRegionFactory depending on your needs/configuration.